# Generic Generics: "Syntax error on token "extends", , expected"

Tags: java, generics

```
public interface View{...

public interface Control<V extends View>{...

public class RemoteControl<C extends Control<V extends View>> implements Control<V>{...
```

gives me a "Syntax error on token "extends", , expected" on "V extends View" for the RemoteControl class.

I guess the following alternative was possible

```
public class RemoteControl<C extends Control<V>,V extends View> implements Control<V>
{...
```

Still I wonder if this cannot be done in a more implicit way since the latter would require a redundant declaration of the View. I.e.:

```
public class TVRemoteControl extends RemoteControl<TVControl,TvView> implements TVControl{...
```

vs

```
public class TVRemoteControl extends RemoteControl<TVControl> implements TVControl{...
```

Maybe I'm just stuck in a box again, but is it possible to get the "generic Generics" in a more elegant way

Comment: I've tried to come up with a solution, but I think you already said it: It can't be done the way you want it and you have to do it the way you described later. Even though I couldn't find any clues to your problem here, I'll refer you to this helpful site: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html

Comment: How about `public class RemoteControl<C extends Control<?>>`. Should it really matter for a remote control what kind of view the control that is being controlled remotely is using?

Comment: I feel sympathy for all java generics questions...

Answer (score 4):

You suggest:

> I guess the following alternative was possible
>
> ```
> public class RemoteControl<C extends Control<V>,V extends View> implements Control<V>{}
> ```

This is the correct solution, although I would normally write it as (for readability):

```
public class RemoteControl<V extends View, C extends Control<V>> implements Control<V>{}
```

You are typing `RemoteControl` on a `Control` object which is also typed on an object that `extends View`. As such you need to provide the implementation of `View` that types the `Control` object that types your `RemoteControl` object.

I guess you could interpret your question as saying, why do I have to provide `V` - shouldn't it be implied from the `<C extends Control<V>>`. To which, the answer is *no*, you need to provide a type for `V` to ensure that the right type of `Control` is provided (i.e. that it `extends Control<V>`)

If you don't care what type `View` the `Control` object is typed on, you don't need to type `Control` in the `RemoteControl`:

```
public class RemoteControl<C extends Control> implements Control{}
```

However, the fact `Control` is typed on `V extends View` and `RemoteControl implements Control<V>`, rather suggests that you do...