# Java generic class of another generic class

Tags: java, generics, interface, dao

I have a base generic class representing all objects of my model that have an identifier of whatever type:

```
public abstract class IdObject<T> {
    private T    id;
    public  T    getId()     { return this.id; }
    public  void setId(T id) { this.id = id;   }
}
```

Then, I have an super-interface representing the DAO for those IdObject objects:

```
public interface IdObjectDAO<T extends IdObject<U>> {
    public T getObjectById(U id);
}
```

but I get the compiler error of "U cannot be resolved to a type". If I change the interface definition by:

```
public interface IdObjectDAO<T extends IdObject<U extends Object>> {...}
```

I get the compiler error of "Syntax error on token "extends", , expected". The only way to define the interface without compiler errors is:

```
public interface IdObjectDAO<T extends IdObject<? extends Object>> {...}
```

but then I don't have a type alias (U) for the `public T getObjectId(U id)` method. The only solution I've found to solve it is using 2 type parameters:

```
public interface IdObjectDAO<T extends IdObject<U>, U> {...}
```

but I want to avoid using those 2 type parameters to avoid specifying the identifier type in model and DAO classes:

```
public class     Person    extends IdObject<Integer> {...}
public interface PersonDAO extends IdObjectDAO<Person, Integer> {...}
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^ <== avoid this
```

Can anybody think in another way to implement this generic of generic or define the `IdObjectDAO` interface?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the two parameter version is the correct and only way to do this. You're expecting the compiler to be able to "look inside" your IdObject for the id type, and that's just not possible.

Comment: Try this

public interface IdObjectDAO<T,U> {
    public T getObjectById(U id);
}

Comment: This should also answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953029/generic-generics-syntax-error-on-token-extends-expected

Answer (score 1):

An interface is not just defined by its name, it consists of the signatures of all methods defined in it. Since you have the method

```
public T getObjectById(U id);
```

your interface is generic in both `T` and `U`. There is no way for the interface to determine `U` from `IdObject<U>`, so you'll have to specify it explicitly if you want compile time type safety.

If you really insist on only providing `T` as a generic parameter, the two (pretty bad) workarounds I can come up with are:

1) Lose type safety:

```
public interface IdObjectDAO<T extends IdObject<?>> {
    public T getObjectById(Object id);
}
```

If you implement `equals` of `U` correctly, you can still successfully call

```
id.equals(t.getId());
```

for an object `t` of type `T`.

2) Wrap your id in an object of type `T`:

```
public interface IdObjectDAO<T extends IdObject<?>> {
    public T getObjectBySample(T sample);
}
```

You can call this like:

```
Integer id = 5;
Person sample = new Person(id);
Person object = personDao.getObjectBySample(sample);
```