# SortedSet of comparable types

Tags: java

Trying to write my class as shown below gives a compilation error

```
public class CustomTreeSet<T extends Comparable<T>> implements SortedSet<T extends Comparable<T>> {

}
```

Error:

```
Syntax error on token "extends", , expected
```

The error occurs at the extends token here:

```
SortedSet<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

Can you help me figure out how do I make my class work with Comparable types only. Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic Generics: "Syntax error on token "extends", , expected"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953029/generic-generics-syntax-error-on-token-extends-expected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only declare the generic type parameter T (and its type bound once) :

```
public class CustomTreeSet<T extends Comparable<T>> implements SortedSet<T> {
```